# nginx php urls paths use a file

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

hope somebody can help me, Im trying to force nginx config to show specific files when the a url is reached, example:

/contact uses contact.php

/shop?something=x uses shop.php

/shop/xxxxx uses category.php

/shop/sale/xxxx?something=x uses product.php

/tienda/xxxxx uses categoria.php

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

/shop/xxxxx uses category.php:

```
rewrite ^/shop/(.*)$ /category.php?category=$1 last;
```

Check out NGINX rewriting: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

As well, you can check out: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/08/nginx-rewrite-examples/

I would highly recommend using some sort of framework. URL rewriting can become very hard to maintain really quickly.